# Excel: Need to round up or down based off the number after the period in excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, rounding

Novice Excel user here. I am needing a formula that will round down to the nearest whole number for anything equal to .3 and below and I need to round up to the nearest whole number for anything equal to .4 and above.

[Current Results and Results needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50FNE.png)

This is what I currently have =IF(RIGHT(F16,2) > ".4",CEILING(F16,1),FLOOR(F16,1)) and it seems to just be using the basic if lower than.5 rounds down and if greater or equal to .5 rounds up. Can someone lend me a hand? Thanks so much!

Comment: Try: `=ROUND(F16+0.1,0)`

Comment: Also note that you have not specified behavior for a case where `0.3<n<0.4`.